# Convert a MS SQL Function to MySQL referencing an assembly created by Yaddress

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

Yaddress.net created a user-defined function for use with MS SQL that appears to integrate with their address correction service. I know the setup script doesn't work with MySQL, but I don't know enough about MySQL to know if it ***can*** work with MySQL. I've done some web searches on creating assemblies and enabling permissions, but I don't find a clear path to converting the setup script. Any help is appreciated.

-- Enable CLR integration

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

-- Set proper permissions on the database

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database Name] 
SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO
```

-- Create assemply from the DLL
-- Replace the path as appropriate

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY YAddressSqlFunction
FROM 'C:\temp\YAddressSqlFunction.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
GO
```

-- Create a User Defined Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION ProcessAddress(@AddressLine1 nvarchar(255), @AddressLine2 nvarchar(255),
                                @UserKey nvarchar(255))
RETURNS TABLE 
(
        ErrorCode int,
        ErrorMessage nvarchar(255),
        AddressLine1 nvarchar(255),
        AddressLine2 nvarchar(255),
        Number nvarchar(255),
        PreDir nvarchar(255),
        Street nvarchar(255),
        Suffix nvarchar(255),
        PostDir nvarchar(255),
        Sec nvarchar(255),
        SecNumber nvarchar(255),
        City nvarchar(255),
        State nvarchar(255),
        Zip nvarchar(255),
        Zip4 nvarchar(255),
        County nvarchar(255),
        StateFP nvarchar(255),
        CountyFP nvarchar(255),
        CensusTract nvarchar(255),
        CensusBlock nvarchar(255),
        Latitude float,
        Longitude float,
        GeocodePrecision int,
        TimeZoneOffset int,
        DstObserved bit,
        SalesTaxRate smallmoney,
        SalesTaxJurisdiction nvarchar(255)
)
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME YAddressSqlFunction.YAddressSqlFunction.InitMethod
GO
```

-- Test the function

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProcessAddress('506 Fourth Avenue Unit 1', 'Asbury Prk, NJ', NULL)
```